# Geometries using a user defined coordinate reference system do not validate in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-spatial

While upgrading our Oracle database from 11.2.0.3.0 to 12.1.0.2.0, we have experienced an issue where the SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT function in Oracle Spatial and Graph returns a non TRUE result for a geometry specified using a user defined coordinate reference system. The same geometry (using the user defined coordinate system) on an 11g database returns TRUE when passed through the same function.

The coordinate system is defined as follows:

```
INSERT INTO sdo_coord_sys (
  coord_sys_id
, coord_sys_name
, coord_sys_type
, dimension
, information_source
, data_source
)
VALUES (
  1006422
, 'Ellipsoidal 2D CS. Axes: latitude, longitude. Orientations: north, east.  UoM: sec'
, 'ellipsoidal'
, 2
, NULL
, NULL
)
/

INSERT INTO sdo_coord_axes(
  coord_sys_id
, coord_axis_name_id
, coord_axis_orientation
, coord_axis_abbreviation
, uom_id
, "ORDER"
)
VALUES(
  1006422
, 9901
, 'north'
, 'Lat'
, 10003
, 1
)
/

INSERT INTO sdo_coord_axes(
  coord_sys_id
, coord_axis_name_id
, coord_axis_orientation
, coord_axis_abbreviation
, uom_id
, "ORDER"
) VALUES(
 1006422
, 9902
, 'east'
, 'Long'
, 10003
, 2
)
/

INSERT INTO sdo_coord_ref_system (
  srid
, coord_ref_sys_name
, coord_ref_sys_kind
, coord_sys_id
, datum_id
, geog_crs_datum_id
, source_geog_srid
, projection_conv_id
, cmpd_horiz_srid
, cmpd_vert_srid
, information_source
, data_source
, is_legacy
, legacy_code
, legacy_wktext
, legacy_cs_bounds
, is_valid
, supports_sdo_geometry
)
VALUES (
  1004230
, 'ED50 (Decimal Seconds)'
, 'GEOGRAPHIC2D'
, 1006422
, 6230
, 6230
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, 'FALSE'
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, 'TRUE'
, 'TRUE'
)
/
```

When you go to use this coordinate system to create and validate a geometry on a 12c database using the geometry below, you get an ORA-13356 (Adjacent points in a geometry are redundant) error. If you use the same geometry on an 11g database TRUE is returned.

```
SELECT sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context(
  mdsys.sdo_geometry(
    2003
  , 1004230
  , NULL
  , sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 1)
  , sdo_ordinate_array(0, 219000, 720, 219000, 720, 219600, 0, 219600, 0, 219000)
  )
, 0.05
)
FROM dual
/
```

We have tried setting the SPATIAL_VECTOR_ACCELERATION parameter to TRUE, we had it set to FALSE originally, and the geometry still does not validate successfully.

The coordinate system we have defined represents ED50 decimal seconds. We use decimal seconds instead of decimal degrees to not loose precision when manipulating geometries. The example below show a loss of precision when converting from Degrees, Minutes, Seconds to Decimal Degrees and back.

```
Degrees, Minutes, Seconds to Decimal Degrees 
50° 22' 00.000"N --> 50.36667°N 

Decimal Degrees to Degrees, Minutes, Seconds 
50.36667°N --> 50° 22' 00.120"N
```

As Oracle does not provide a decimal second coordinate system we have created our own user defined one. The example below shows no loss of precision when converting from Degrees, Minutes, Seconds to Decimal Seconds and back

```
Degrees, Minutes, Seconds to Decimal Seconds 
50° 22' 00.000"N --> 181320"N 

Decimal Seconds to Degrees, Minutes, Seconds 
181320"N --> 50° 22' 00.000"N
```

Does anyone know of a reason why our user defined coordinate system may no longer work since upgrading to 12c?

Comment: A behavior change from one version to the next seems to me like a bug. Did you file a SR with Oracle Support ?

Comment: Hi Albert, I agree it does look like a bug. We have an open SR with Oracle Support. They have recently said that they have enhanced the VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT function in 12c and fixed a bug that exists in 11g. I am waiting on them to update me on why our geometry seems to be invalid but thought I would see if anyone had experienced similar problems when upgrading.

Comment: Oracle has confirmed that this issue is a bug. It looks like it affects 11.2.0.4, 12.1.0.2, 12.2.0.2 as well as the current internal beta of 19.0.0.0.0. The bug reference is Bug 28207390.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle have released a one off patch to solve this issue on version 12.1.0.2. This patch can be downloaded from the My Oracle Support page. The patch id is 28207390.

**Important:** The README associated to this bug at the time of writing does not contain a crucial post installation step without which applying this patch will not resolve the problem.

Once the patch has been installed you need to do the following steps:

```
> cd $ORACLE_HOME/md/admin

> sqlplus / as sysdba

> alter session set current_schema = mdsys; 

> @prvtgeom.plb
```

This should result in the following output:

```
Session altered. 

Package body created. 

No errors. 

Synonym created. 

Grant succeeded. 

Grant succeeded. 

Session altered.
```

After these steps have been completed running the sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context statement from the question returns TRUE.